# Why does my javascript cause the second image in my carousel to load first?

Tags: javascript, carousel

Here is the script added to the bootstrap carousel that's somehow causing the 2nd image to load first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                    interval: 10000
                })
                $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
                    var next = $(this).next();
                    if (!next.length) {
                        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                    }
                    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    if (next.next().length > 0) {
                        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    } else {
                        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Probably because your function begins with `var next = $(this).next();` when it should work on `$(this)` first.

Comment: I was wondering about `var next = $(this).next();` that line too. It'd be helpful if you can add comment on each line to understand your intention

Comment: I am not very well trained in javascript and copied the code from another site. The carousel shows some of the slide before and after the one you are viewing and contains the controls. When the page loads, it shows 30% of slide 1 to the left, side 2 (full) in the middle and 30% slide 3 to the right. How would I get the last slide to load first?